# Failed to create InputInitializerManager error - TEZ on HIVE

Tags: hive, hadoop2, apache-tez, bigdata

I have installed Apache Tez 0.8.1, Hadoop version 2.7.0 and Hive version 2.01.I am able to successfully run the Map Reduce Jobs.But when I configure hive and tried to run a simple count query, it returned the below error.From the error it is trying to look for a jar,I have placed the jar in classpath but still error did not resolve.

Please help me in resolving this.Thanks in Advance!!.

```
    hive> select count(*) from sample1;
    Query ID = root_20160728215555_a58e91a6-8913-4a57-8715-bc1739a2cb02
    Total jobs = 1
    Launching Job 1 out of 1


    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        VERTICES      MODE        STATUS  TOTAL  COMPLETED  RUNNING  PENDING  FAILED  KILLED  
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Map 1            container        FAILED     -1          0        0       -1       0       0  
    Reducer 2        container        KILLED      1          0        0        1       0       0  
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    VERTICES: 00/02  [>>--------------------------] 0%    ELAPSED TIME: 0.17 s     
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Status: Failed
    Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1469720608711_0011_1_00, diagnostics=[Vertex vertex_1469720608711_0011_1_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:INIT_FAILURE, Fail to create InputInitializerManager, org.apache.tez.dag.api.TezReflectionException: Unable to instantiate class with 1 arguments: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveSplitGenerator
        at org.apache.tez.common.ReflectionUtils.getNewInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:70)
        at org.apache.tez.common.ReflectionUtils.createClazzInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:89)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager.createInitializer(RootInputInitializerManager.java:138)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager.runInputInitializers(RootInputInitializerManager.java:115)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl.setupInputInitializerManager(VertexImpl.java:4676)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl.access$4300(VertexImpl.java:204)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl$InitTransition.handleInitEvent(VertexImpl.java:3445)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl$InitTransition.transition(VertexImpl.java:3394)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl$InitTransition.transition(VertexImpl.java:3375)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$MultipleInternalArc.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:385)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.access$300(StateMachineFactory.java:46)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$InternalStateMachine.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:448)
        at org.apache.tez.state.StateMachineTez.doTransition(StateMachineTez.java:57)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl.handle(VertexImpl.java:1975)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl.handle(VertexImpl.java:203)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster$VertexEventDispatcher.handle(DAGAppMaster.java:2090)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster$VertexEventDispatcher.handle(DAGAppMaster.java:2076)
        at org.apache.tez.common.AsyncDispatcher.dispatch(AsyncDispatcher.java:183)
        at org.apache.tez.common.AsyncDispatcher$1.run(AsyncDispatcher.java:114)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at org.apache.tez.common.ReflectionUtils.getNewInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:68)
        ... 20 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapred/split/SplitLocationProvider
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveSplitGenerator.<init>(HiveSplitGenerator.java:96)
        ... 25 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.split.SplitLocationProvider
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 26 more
    ]
    Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1469720608711_0011_1_01, diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill in NEW state., Vertex vertex_1469720608711_0011_1_01 [Reducer 2] killed/failed due to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]
    DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:1
```

**UPDATE:**

After I face the above issue, I have copied the hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar in hive lib folder.After that I am facing another issue while starting hive.From the trace I could figure out that there is some illegal argument passed.

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1550)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3080)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3108)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:543)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:516)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:712)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:648)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1548)
        ... 14 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized Hadoop major version number: 1.2.1
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getMajorVersion(ShimLoader.java:165)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.loadShims(ShimLoader.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getHadoopShims(ShimLoader.java:93)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getDataSourceProps(ObjectStore.java:376)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:268)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:62)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:58)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:517)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:482)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:544)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:370)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5762)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:219)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:67)
```

Comment: Any Tez with Hive experts, please help me in resolving this.I am not able to proceed further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with the Apache Tez version.Apache Tez 0.8.1 is not compatible with Hadoop 2.7.0 and hive 2.0.1.

Have downloaded 0.8.4 src and built it which has resolved the issue.

Thanks!!.